# iterating through carousel objects in selenium with python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

using selenium i want to iterate through the games in the carousel at the top of gog.com 
i want to print all the prices and below are 2 random xpaths to the information i want in the carousel

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/a[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/span/span

/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/a[10]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/span/span
```

this makes me want to iterate through the first a element. each a being a different game. but it either can not find that path, returns no data or returns an object with no attribute .text or .innerhtml such that i cant get the info i want

below is my script

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"../Downloads/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.gog.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/a[10]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/span/span")))

for i in range(15):
    i+=1;
    A = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/a["+str(i)+"]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/span[2]/span"
    try:
        print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(A));
        print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(A).text);
        print(str(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(A)));
    finally:
        pass
```

below is an example of the object it returns

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3ec9e534c096a49d3110dea89fea3864", element="0bf0c6b6-fb35-4e26-8bf4-acbb7431eafb")>]
```

below is an example of the error it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\mi faaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaak.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(A).text);
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

below is an example of the actual element i want the information from

`<span class="big-spot__price-amount" ng-bind="tile.data.price.finalAmount">13.69</span>`

how can i make it print all the prices in the carousel at the top of this page https://www.gog.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are using ***find_elements_by_xpath*** method for a xpath for single element, which is returning a list. So instead use  ***find_element_by_xpath***.

Suggestion: Instead of writing absolute xpath, make it generic. Make your code look like this:

```
carousel_xpath = '//your generic xpath here'
carousel_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(carousel_xpath)
for carousel in carousel_elements:
    print(carousel.text)
    //do your things here
```