# iterating through carousel objects by xpath in python with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

i want to iterate through this carousel at the top of gog.com. it advertises games for sale. i want to iterate through each slide of the carousel and get the price of each. I took 2 xpaths for prices of different games.

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/a[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/span/span

/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/a[10]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/span/span
```

i figure i could just iterate through the a tags like

```
for i in range(15):
    i+=1;
    A = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/a["+str(i)+"]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/span[2]/span"
    try:
        print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(A));
```

but i cant get it to print the price.

bellow is my full script

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"../Downloads/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.gog.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/a[10]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/span/span")))

for i in range(15):
    i+=1;
    A = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/a["+str(i)+"]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/span[2]/span"
    try:
        print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(A));
        print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(A).text);
        print(str(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(A)));
    finally:
        pass
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iterating through carousel objects in selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60948818/iterating-through-carousel-objects-in-selenium-with-python)